# Why does this pyside code not update its widget/view?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am new to `pyside` and probably do not understand quite well the concepts of the GUI libraries. I have a specific question to the following code (python3.3), in which I create a view of a table, and a button. Once the button is pressed, data is added to the date of the widget, and the table should be redrawn. But the table does not update itself with the added contents.

How can I fix the code so the table updates/redraws itself after I press the 'Do_something' button?

For additional suggestions on my code I would be very thankful!

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        # this list represents the database
        self.data_list = [
            ('John', 'Connor', 'terminated'),
            ('Buzz', 'Lightyea', 'animated')
        ]
        self.header = ['name', 'lastname', 'extra']

        # set basic window stuff
        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 970, 450)
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Stock Overview")

        # add the model to the view
        self.table_model = MyTableModel(self, self.data_list, self.header)
        self.table_view = QTableView()
        self.table_view.setModel(self.table_model)

        # add the table to the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self) 
        layout.addWidget(self.table_view)
        btn1 = QPushButton("Do_something", self)
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.do_something)            

        # add some button to the layout
        action_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        action_layout.addStretch(1)
        action_layout.addWidget(btn1)
        layout.addLayout(action_layout)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def do_something(self):

        # update the 'database'
        self.data_list.append(('Harry','Potter','wizated'))
        print("data has been updated: ", self.data_list)

        # required to be redrawn here
        index1 = self.table_model.createIndex(0,0)
        index2 = self.table_model.createIndex(self.table_model.rowCount(self)+1,       self.table_model.columnCount(self))
        self.table_model.dataChanged.emit(index1, index2)

class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent, mylist, header, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.mylist = mylist
        self.header = header

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.mylist)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.mylist[0])

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        return self.mylist[index.row()][index.column()]

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.header[col]
        return None

app = QApplication([])
win = MyWindow()
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the docs a bit more it turns out that after adding new data row you need to emit the [`rowsInserted`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted) signal. So, the following is sufficient:

```
def do_something(self):
    self.data_list.append(('Harry','Potter','wizated'))
    newRow = len(self.data_list) - 1
    self.table_model.rowsInserted.emit(QModelIndex(), newRow, newRow)
```

Comment: Finally - it works! It would have taken me ages to find the correct method from the documentation. Thanks